# Issue regarding ripple effect in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to implement a ripple effect while I press my button . The border of the button has been made by me (mentioned in the item tag at the end) . Also I want a bordered ripple hence I use "mask" as the id. If I don't implement solid tags and a color to it inside the mask , ripple effect is not implemented . What could be the reason for it

```
<ripple
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/colorHighlighted">


    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/teal_700"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_circular_color_accent_border"/>

</ripple>
```

Comment: If you are using `MaterialComponents` and `Button` it would be much easier by styling it using the `rippleColor` attribute.

Comment: Yes it worked that way too